# How to get Sitecore template branches to use default language?

Tags: templates, branch

We are trying to use Sitecore template branches to create templates for different pages, i.e. "About us", "Contact", "Faq" etc. In that way, we hope to ease the job of the Sitecore editor, when they have to setup a Sitecore on a new language.
For us, a Sitecore template branch consists of a page template and then a number of page components (renderings) added on top of it:

[image]

**Problem**

Our problem arise, when we want to create an instance of the Sitecore branch template in a different language, than the language of the branch template. Our branch templates are always created in "en", but if we want to create an instance of the branch template in "en-us", it does not contain any page components. We would have to create a branch template in "en-us" in order to get the instance of the branch template to contain any components.

Is there any way of getting around this?

Comment: Hi @Hos- how about we write a PSE script and create a language version for the selected item and child items in the language we want?

Comment: are the renderings placed on the shared layout of the page template's standard values?

Comment: No they are not and I guess you are right that is the issue. However, the renderings are added through the exp editor so I guess that is just how Sitecore adds page components?

Comment: You can add to "Shared Layout" via EE

Comment: Aha, I was not aware of that. That totally solved my issue. I don't know if @MarkCassidy or Dregn Gashi should get the "Mark as answer", but if either of you leave an answer I will make sure to mark it as accepted solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to go about it. You could add all the language versions you need for your Branch Template items, and add Presentation Details for all of them.

Alternatively you could edit the `Shared Layout` as opposed to the `Final Layout` in Experience Editor. Find it under the Presentation ribbon.

[image]